# Is it possible to defining multiple relationships between two tables in Gorm?

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, go-gorm

I'm building a simple app for users to add songs to a list, and to vote on songs, and I'm building the backend in Go, using Gorm with a Postgres database.

Here are my structures:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string `json:"name"`        // Name of user
    DisplayName string `json:"displayName"` // Display name of user
    Password    string `json:"password"`    // Password
    SongsAdded  []Song `json:"songs"`       // Songs added by user
}

type Song struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title    string `json:"title"`    // Song title
    Artist   string `json:"artist"`   // Song artist
    ImageURL string `json:"imageUrl"` // URL to image
    UserId   uint   `json:"userId"`   // ID of user that added the song
    Likes    []User `json:"likes"`    // List of users that like the song
    Dislikes []User `json:"dislikes"` // List of users that dislike the song
}
```

I'd like to keep track of which user added a song to the list (hence the `SongsAdded` field in the `User` struct, and the `UserId` field in the `Song` struct).  To keep track of the votes, I'd like to add users to either the `Likes` or `Dislikes` `User` slices in the `Song` struct.  However, I'm getting this error when I try to `AutoMigrate`:

```
invalid field found for struct main.Song's field Likes: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
```

I imagine that I am confusing Gorm by having three different references to `User` in the same struct, but I am not quite sure how to address this.  I suppose I could change Likes and Dislikes to slices of `string` or `uint` and put usernames or user IDs there instead, but I'd be happier if the reference was to the actual objects so I don't have to perform additional DB searches.

Any suggestions on how to either redesign my data structures, or configure them properly so that this will work?

Using the above structures, I tried running `db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Song{})` but I am getting an error when the `Likes` field is reached, and the `Song` DB table is not created.

I expected both tables to be created without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the many to many relationship (each song can have many users who liked/disliked, each user can like/dislike many songs):

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string `json:"name"`        // Name of user
    DisplayName string `json:"displayName"` // Display name of user
    Password    string `json:"password"`    // Password
    SongsAdded  []Song `json:"songs"`       // Songs added by user
    Likes       []Song `json:"likes" gorm:"many2many:user_likes;"`    // List of songs that this user likes
    Dislikes    []Song `json:"dislikes" gorm:"many2many:user_dislikes;"` // List of songs that this user dislikes
```

}
}

```
type Song struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title    string `json:"title"`    // Song title
    Artist   string `json:"artist"`   // Song artist
    ImageURL string `json:"imageUrl"` // URL to image
    UserId   uint   `json:"userId"`   // ID of user that added the song
    Likes    []User `json:"likes" gorm:"many2many:user_likes;"`    // List of users that like the song
    Dislikes []User `json:"dislikes" gorm:"many2many:user_dislikes;"` // List of users that dislike the song
}
```

see https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html

And then you'll need to do something like

```
db.Preload("Likes").Preload("Dislikes").Load(&user)
```